# Why only a part of my list are write in a csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to python trying to build my first script. I want to  scrap a list of url and export it in a csv file.

My script is well executed however when opening the csv file only few line of data are written. When I'm printing the list I'm trying to write (`sharelist` and `sharelist1`), the print is complete whereas the csv file is not.

Here is a part of my code :

```
  for url in urllist[10:1000]:  
                # query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
        try:
            page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
                if e.getcode() == 404: # eheck the return code
                    continue
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

                    # Take out the <div> of name and get its value
        name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'nb-shares'})
        if name_box is None:
          continue
        share = name_box.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing

        # save the data in tuple
        sharelist.append(url)
        sharelist1.append(share)

    # open a file for writing.
        csv_out = open('mycsv.csv', 'wb')

    # create the csv writer object.
        mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)

    # writerow - one row of data at a time.
        for row in zip(sharelist, sharelist1):
            mywriter.writerow(row)

    # always make sure that you close the file.
    # otherwise you might find that it is empty.
        csv_out.close()
```

Not sure which part of my code I should share here. Please tell me if it's not enough !

Comment: Opening and closing your file at every iteration of the `for` loop is the heart of problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are opening the file every time you run through the loop. This essentially will overwrite the previous file.

```
# open a file for writing.
    csv_out = open('mycsv.csv', 'wb')

# create the csv writer object.
    mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)

# writerow - one row of data at a time.
    for row in zip(sharelist, sharelist1):
        mywriter.writerow(row)

# always make sure that you close the file.
# otherwise you might find that it is empty.
    csv_out.close()
```

Either open the file before the loop, or open it with the append option.

This is option one (note the indentation):

```
# open a file for writing.
csv_out = open('mycsv.csv', 'wb')

# create the csv writer object.
mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)
for url in urllist[10:1000]:  
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
            if e.getcode() == 404: # eheck the return code
                continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'nb-shares'})
    if name_box is None:
      continue
    share = name_box.text.strip()

    # save the data in tuple
    sharelist.append(url)
    sharelist1.append(share)

# writerow - one row of data at a time.
    for row in zip(sharelist, sharelist1):
        mywriter.writerow(row)

# always make sure that you close the file.
# otherwise you might find that it is empty.
csv_out.close()
```

This is option 2:

```
for url in urllist[10:1000]:  
            # query the website and return the html to the variable 'page'
    try:
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
            if e.getcode() == 404: # eheck the return code
                continue
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

                # Take out the <div> of name and get its value
    name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'nb-shares'})
    if name_box is None:
      continue
    share = name_box.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing

    # save the data in tuple
    sharelist.append(url)
    sharelist1.append(share)

# open a file for writing.
    csv_out = open('mycsv.csv', 'ab')

# create the csv writer object.
    mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)

# writerow - one row of data at a time.
    for row in zip(sharelist, sharelist1):
        mywriter.writerow(row)

# always make sure that you close the file.
# otherwise you might find that it is empty.
    csv_out.close()
```

Comment: I thought about that however I didn't find a solution. when I'm trying to open my csv before or close it outside the loop I have some error. Could you guide me to a solution ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been found and the best solution for files is to use `with` keyword which permits to close the file at the end automatically :

```
with open('mycsv.csv', 'wb') as csv_out:
    mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)
    for url in urllist[10:1000]:  

        try:
            page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
                if e.getcode() == 404:
                    continue
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'nb-shares'})
        if name_box is None:
          continue
        share = name_box.text.strip()

        # save the data in tuple
        sharelist.append(url)
        sharelist1.append(share)

        for row in zip(sharelist, sharelist1):
            mywriter.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Open a file for writing, using a context manager, that way, you don't need to close the file explicitly.

```
with open('mycsv.csv', 'w') as file_obj:
    mywriter = csv.writer(file_obj)
    for url in urllist[10:1000]:
        try:
            page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
                if e.getcode() == 404: # check the return code
                    continue
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        name_box = soup.find(attrs={'class': 'nb-shares'})
        if name_box is None:
            continue
        share = name_box.text.strip()
        # no need to use zip, and append in 2 lists as they're really expensive calls,
        # and by the looks of it, I think it'll create duplicate rows in your file
        mywriter.writerow((url, share))
```

Comment: the difference between my answer and SyedElec is the 'w' vs 'wb' used in the with statement, for which the later will cause an AttributeError: __exit__ as the csv.writer doesn't implement it. (and the zip, append optimization)